# C# Custom String Split

Tags: c#, string, split

Heyo out there.

I got a little problem which I came across lately. I need a string to be split in a certain format:

The string syntax looks like this:

```
[date time]sender///receiver///message///server
```

Wanted output (sender, receiver and server get saved):

```
[date time]message
```

Example:

```
[2015-04-14 13:45:00]Aeon///Test///Aeon : this is my test message///S1
[2015-04-14 13:45:00]Aeon : this is my test message
```

---

So far my code looks like this (I'll explain the problem below):

```
private string FormatLine(string input, out string server, out string sender, out string receiver)
{
      string output = input;
      string[] separator = new string[] { "///" };
      string[] temp;

      temp = input.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);
      server = temp[temp.Length - 1];
      sender = temp[1];
      receiver = temp[2];
      temp[1] = String.Empty;
      temp[2] = String.Empty;
      temp[temp.Length - 1] = String.Empty;

      output = String.Join("", temp);
      //other format/filter algorithms

      return output;
}
```

---

This works well until the separator is used in the message string:

```
[2015-04-14 13:45:00]Aeon///Test///Aeon : this is my test message :////S1
[2015-04-14 13:45:00]Aeon : this is my test message :
```

server will be "/S1" instead of "S1"

```
[2015-04-14 13:45:00]Aeon///Test///Aeon : this is my/// test message///S1
[2015-04-14 13:45:00]Aeon : this is my
```

server will be " test message" instead of "S1" and the program might run into further troubles

---

Is there any way to only split the string on the **first two** and the **last** appearance of the separator?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have single predefined template with predefined separator?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to glue back the parts you don't want to get split. Something like this should work:

```
var message = "";
for (int i = 2; i<splitArray.Lenght -2;i++)
    message+=splitArray[i]+@"\\\";
```

EDIT: I might have got the index numbers wrong but you get the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not using `string.Split`. You'd need to use RegEx to achieve that. Define a regular expression, which describes to string to match, define it to capture only the complete line and add the '/'-char to the group of allowed characters of the message-group.
Something like the following expression should work:

```
^\[(?P<date>\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\)](?P<sender>[^/]+)///(?P<tag>[^/]+)///(?P<message>.+)///(?P<server>.+$)
```

Websites like [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) help you to create and refine the expression. You will probably have to do some optimization with that expression, to be sure to handle all your cases. It is just an basic example.

Don't think of splitting here, but of groups. The ?P gives each group a name, so you can better find it later, in the GroupCollection of your match.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to work with regex then this should work as long as the sender and receiver does not contain `///`.  It should be efficient too, since you never iterate over the same section of the string more than once; possibly more efficient than a regex but I am not positive on that.  It is certainly easier to understand than a regex, anyways.

```
string test = @"[date time]sender///receiver///message/////server";
int senderEnd = test.IndexOf("///");
int receiverEnd = test.IndexOf("///", senderEnd + 3);
int messageEnd = test.LastIndexOf("///", test.Length);

string message = test.Substring(receiverEnd + 3, messageEnd - (receiverEnd + 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. The code have to be rewritten to include error handling and format checking. For example you have to check if the IndexOf methods returns -1 but you'll get the idea. Good luck

```
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        string input = "[2015-04-14 13:45:00]Aeon///Test///Aeon : this is my/// test message///S1";
        const string sep = "///";

        int first = input.IndexOf(sep, System.StringComparison.Ordinal);
        int second = input.IndexOf(sep, first + sep.Length, System.StringComparison.Ordinal);
        int last = input.LastIndexOf(sep, System.StringComparison.Ordinal);

        int dl = "[2015-04-14 13:45:00]".Length;
        Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(dl, first - dl));
        Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(first + sep.Length, second - first - sep.Length));
        Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(second + sep.Length, last - second - sep.Length));
        Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(last + sep.Length, input.Length - last - sep.Length));

    }
```